# Printing a binary tree in order

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a problem to convert a sorted array to a binary tree. I think that I have done it. Now I just want to print all items after conversion to double check it.

My question is that my printing part doesn't print all items. Something is wrong in the method 'inOrderTraversalHelper'.

```
class Program
{
    // Given an array where elements are sorted in ascending order, 
    // convert it to a height balanced BST
    static int[] arr = new int[8] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    static TreeNode node { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         node = SortedArrayToBST(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);
         inOrderTraversal();
    }

    static void inOrderTraversal()
    {
        inOrderTraversalHelper(node);
    }
    static void inOrderTraversalHelper(TreeNode r)
    {
        if (r != null)
        {    
          **// UPDATED**

            inOrderTraversalHelper(r.leftNode);
             Console.Write("{0}   ", r.data);
            inOrderTraversalHelper(r.rightNode);
        }
    }
    static TreeNode SortedArrayToBST(int[] a,int start,int end)
    {
        if (start > end) return null;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(a[mid]);
        node.leftNode= SortedArrayToBST(a, start, mid-1);
        node.rightNode = SortedArrayToBST(a, mid + 1, end);
        return node;
    }
}

public class TreeNode
{
    public int data;
    public TreeNode leftNode;
    public TreeNode rightNode;

    public TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you seeing? It's hard to say without that information.

Comment: 4,1,0,2,3,6,5,7,8. 0 was unexpected.

Comment: You know that your in-order traversal function is not in-order, but pre-order, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter which order, the elements set doesn't match the original array. pre-oder shouldn't contain '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SortedArrayToBST`, you work with the index `mid`, rather than with the element `a[mid]`, change:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(mid);
```

to:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(a[mid]);
```

In the call to the `SortedArrayToBST` function, you need to pass array size - 1, since the end condition in inclusive, change:

```
node = SortedArrayToBST(arr, 0, arr.Length);
```

to:

```
node = SortedArrayToBST(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);
```

Also, your `inOrderTraversalHelper` function isn't actually in-order, but rather post-order.

Comment: By the code, the printing result will be "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8". It is wrong. You can try it.

Comment: What's wrong with 1-8 in order? In a BST, the in-order traversal is **supposed** to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are storing the value of the index `mid` not the value *at the index* of `mid`:

```
int mid = (start + end) / 2;
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(mid);
```

You are calculating the value of mid and then passing it in as the data. Instead mid should be the `index` of the value you want. For, example if you had a data set where the data was ordered but non sequential you'd get even stranger results:

```
{-1,22,33,44,55,66,77,100}
```

So your code should probably look up the value at index `mid` instead:

```
var mid = (int)((start + end) / 2.0);
var node = new TreeNode(arr[mid]);
```

Comment: Good spot! Why does calculating mid via a float make a difference, though?

Comment: I corrected it. But your result is wrong, believe me. You can copy and paste to try it.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't in this case.